# smartGwt close clickHandler

Tags: java, gwt, tabs, smartgwt

i am facing a problem with using the smartGWT `CloseClickHandler` , i added it to a tab , it is working good but my problem is, that it delete tha tab before i can do any thing with the event , what i want is to be able to show a confirmation window so the user can be sure he want to close the tab , 
so is there any handler that can do my code before deleting or hiding the tab Or is there any way to handle this situation using  the tab CloseClickHandler ?

my code is :

```
    tabSet = new TabSet();
    tabSet .setWidth100();
    tabSet .setOverflow(Overflow.HIDDEN);
    tabSet .setTabBarThickness(23);
    tabSet .setHeight(23);
    tabSet .setBackgroundColor("#e1dfdf");
    tabSet .setCanCloseTabs(true);
    tabSet .setCloseTabIcon("icons/close_icon.png");
    tabSet .setCloseTabIconSize(12);
    tabSet .addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() { 

        public void onCloseClick(TabCloseClickEvent event) {

            final int tabIndex = ((MyTab)event.getTab()).getId();

            final MyTab = (MyTab)tabSet.getTab(tabIndex);
            int tabId = tab.getTabId();
            int tabType = getType();
            presenter.removeBasket(tabId, tabType);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

First cancel the `TabCloseClickEvent` then do whatever you want to do.

```
tabSet.addCloseClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tab.events.CloseClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onCloseClick(TabCloseClickEvent event) {
        event.cancel();

        final Tab tab = event.getTab();

        SC.confirm("Are you sure? You want to delete " + tab.getTitle()+" tab.",
                new BooleanCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void execute(Boolean value) {
                        if (value != null && value) {
                            tabSet.removeTab(tab);
                        }

                    }
                });

    }
});
```